# For missing value imputation, why not use the fit from test data to transform test data

Tags: scikit-learn, transform, imputation

for missing value imputation in python sklearn, I understand why we can't use validation/test data for fit in the imputer for train data- due to leakage.

However, to impute the missing values in the test set, why not use fit the imputer on the test set, why use the imputer from the training set ? If we use the fit on the test data and transform on the test data, we are not using test for training at all.

Say I have a simple model trying to predict a student monthly expenses using parents salary, with linear regression. In the train set, the parents salaries are all in ranges of 100k - 250k. So, if I use mean imputer, I might get some 150k for missing parents salary. So, I will use this to fill missing train data. 
However, if in my test, if parents salary are all in range of 60k -100k, the mean will be around 75k and I can use that to fill missing values in test set, why use the 150k value based on the train set.
Here if I fit on test set, I am using it just to fill the missing values on test set, but not using it for anything in the train data processing, so why not do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You absolutely **never** should fit the imputer on the test data. The reasoning you are applying here is flawed in terms of machine learning workflow.

I guess the point you are trying to make is that your observations in the test set are very different from the train set, and hence your missing values should be imputed according to other test values that would be more similar. This then probably means you haven't split your train and test sample at random in the first place... which really is a prerequisite for supervised learning.

Your model, once it is trained, is likely to be used for real world predictions.. such as.. predicting the monthly expense of student John Doe. What if John Doe has a missing value? Then obviously your imputer should take the value of the train set (that's what a training set is there for). By evaluating your model with a test set, you want to assess how well your model would predict a new outcome such as John Doe's, and as a result you should mimic this procedure in the test phase as well.